# A confusion about Int::class.java.isInstance() in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

The result of `Int::class.java.isInstance(4)` is false.

But `String::class.java.isInstance("aa")` is true.

What is the correct way of `Int` type checking in the function like this.

```
fun <T> castValue(v: Any?, clazz: Class<T>): T? {
  if (v != null && clazz.isInstance(v) return v as T
  return null
}

val result = castValue(4, Int::class.java)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `reified` type parameter:

```
inline fun <reified T> cast(value:Any?): T? = value as? T
```

And call it like this:

`cast<Boolean>(false)`

Answer (score 1):

`::class.java` is call Java method instead of Kotlin.

If you want to test the type, use `is`

```
val isInt = 1 is Int // true
```

If you want to try cast, use `as?`

```
val num = unknown as? Int // null if it is not Int
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Int::class` refers to the primitive `int` type, but the value is the boxed `Integer` type.

A workaround is to use `Integer::class` instead of `Int::class`, as this will refer to the boxed Java type.

To be more generic, you could use a helper like [Apache Commons `ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#primitiveToWrapper-java.lang.Class-), or maintain a

```
fun primitiveToWrapper(clazz: Class<*>): Class<*> = when (clazz) {
    java.lang.Void.TYPE -> java.lang.Void::class.java
    java.lang.Boolean.TYPE -> java.lang.Boolean::class.java
    java.lang.Byte.TYPE -> java.lang.Byte::class.java
    java.lang.Character.TYPE -> java.lang.Character::class.java
    java.lang.Short.TYPE -> java.lang.Short::class.java
    java.lang.Integer.TYPE -> java.lang.Integer::class.java
    java.lang.Long.TYPE -> java.lang.Long::class.java
    java.lang.Float.TYPE -> java.lang.Float::class.java
    java.lang.Double.TYPE -> java.lang.Double::class.java
    else -> clazz
}
```

lookup table yourself. Unfortunately there is no method built into Java or Kotlin to obtain the wrapper class of a primitive type.

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> castValue(v: Any?, clazz: Class<T>): T? =
    v?.takeIf(primitiveToWrapper(clazz)::isInstance) as T?
```